"Unique" or "Repeated" experiences in memory replay...?
I'm training an RL agent/model (DRL/DQN).
Say that, for each learning step, the memory replay used by the agent to learn, has N elements (experiences) stored, where only X are unique elements (experiences), meaning X <= N.
I wonder whether it would be beneficial for the agent to sample from the whole memory or from a memory with unique elements?
